# Apk Silent installation android

Tags: java, android

I want to know, how to install apk programmatically without using intent(i.e. silent installation without user prompt)?

I did r&d regarding this, only possible if the device is rooted but i saw few application like Appbrain, and airwatch, am asking for enterprice app, is there any workaround for this?

I refer this thread also [Silent installation on Android devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3438637/silent-installation-on-android-devices)

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 3):

You need a rooted device do this.  [ACTION_PACKAGE_INSTALL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_INSTALL) was never actually used and supposedly required being a system app.

```
exec = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"mv /path/to.apk /system/app/theapp.apk"});
```

Comment: Thanks for your post, I want to do this without rooting the device?

Comment: It's a huge security issue so I'd say it's unlikely you're able to do this.

Comment: off course its a huge security but some of the enterprise application did this and also Appbrain did this without rooting the device.