# Auto Updating the Application without replace application warning

Tags: android, auto-update

I have an android application that needs to be automatically updated as soon as new version is available. I have referred the following link for updating the application:

[Updater](https://github.com/RaghavSood/AppaholicsUpdateChecker)

But then it asks before updating that whether i want to replace application. I don't want that warning i want that application should automatically be updated without asking for permission. What can i do for that? Please help me..

Comment: You can't do it without root permissions

Comment: This might be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3438637/450534

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is not possible. Else it would be a security hole because you can force to user to install an unknown application (with malware code). All you can do is asking your users to update (and confirm the dialog) or close the app if they do not.

Comment: But its my application version update .. can't it be done without user intervention using some sort of permission or so??

Comment: Hmm I just checked to permissions and found following one: android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES
So maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803999/install-apps-silently-with-granted-install-packages-permission
But keep in mind that you may scare some users if they see this permision prompting while installing your app the first time.

Comment: i think its not possible to install without asking for permissions from the user. Thanks for your prompt reply. If u get something new please do inform me.